# Setting Post Date Returning "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Tags: wp-insert-post, scheduled-posts

I am using `wp_insert_post` to create post. While executing that function, I also set post date to schedule the post publish date using some variables.

Here is the part of my code:

```
//Intervals
$intsecond = (isset($_POST['awpht_time_second'])) ? $_POST['awpht_time_second'] : 0;
$intminute = (isset($_POST['awpht_time_minute'])) ? $_POST['awpht_time_minute'] : 0;
$inthour = (isset($_POST['awpht_time_hour'])) ? $_POST['awpht_time_hour'] : 0;
$intday = (isset($_POST['awpht_time_day'])) ? $_POST['awpht_time_day'] : 0;
$intmonth = (isset($_POST['awpht_time_month'])) ? $_POST['awpht_time_month'] : 0;
$intyear = (isset($_POST['awpht_time_year'])) ? $_POST['awpht_time_year'] : 0;

// Blog Local Time that can be splitted

$base_year = date('Y', current_time( 'timestamp') );
$base_month = date('m', current_time( 'timestamp') );
$base_day = date('d', current_time( 'timestamp') );
$base_hour = date('H', current_time( 'timestamp') );
$base_minute = date('i', current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
$base_second = date('s', current_time( 'timestamp') );

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {

$awyear = ($i * $intyear) + $base_year;
$awmonth = ($i * $intmonth) + $base_month;
$awday = ($i * $intday) + $base_day;
$awhour = ($i * $inthour) + $base_hour;
$awminute = ($i * $intminute) + $base_minute;
$awsecond = ($i * $intsecond) + $base_second;

$postdate = date($awyear.'-'.$awmonth.'-'.$awday.' '.$awhour.':'.$awminute.':'.$awsecond);


//Check If Post Already Exist/ Prevent Duplicates
if (!get_page_by_title($awpharritle[$i], 'OBJECT', 'post')){

$awpht_the_posts[$i] = array(
  'post_title'    => $awpharritle[$i],
  'post_content'  => $awpht_content{$i},
  'post_date'     => $postdate,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
);

// Insert the post into the database
$awpht_post_id = wp_insert_post( $awpht_the_posts[$i]);
}
```

Each time that code is executed, it always returning a notice:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4028
```

What's wrong with the codes above and is there any other way/s to programmatically mass schedule post based on custom interval? Please don't suggest me a plugin.

Best Regards

Comment: What is `var_dump($awpht_the_posts);`? And why are you constructing an array instead of just overwriting the variable at each iteration?

Comment: Thank you very much for coming to my question. The result containing contents that is some big images. And here is the example of how the date is formatted in the array `" ["post_date"]=> string(17) "2013-11-4 1:42:20" `. Why am I using array? I just following `wp_insert_post` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post documentation and am fetching image files from folder to be created as posts.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here is an easy fix for that problem.

You need to first convert the integer or string to date. See the codes below to understand how to do that:

**First change this line:**

```
$postdate = date($awyear.'-'.$awmonth.'-'.$awday.' '.$awhour.':'.$awminute.':'.$awsecond);
```

**TO**

```
$postdate = $awyear.'-'.$awmonth.'-'.$awday.' '.$awhour.':'.$awminute.':'.$awsecond;
```

Now, convert the `$postdate` to time string by using `strtotime` function.

```
    $cvtpostdate = strtotime($postdate);

$newpostdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $cvtpostdate);
```

Put this `$newpostdate` into the array.

```
$awpht_the_posts[$i] = array(
  'post_title'    => $awpharritle[$i],
  'post_content'  => $awpht_content{$i},
  'post_date'     => $newpostdate, //<========== Newly generated post date.
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
);
```

There will be no more notice, since you are now using the correct date string.